# migrating all the properties file contents to nosql db in Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

We are migrating all the properties file contents (key/value pair) into mongo DB as we use mongo heavily. Right now, we have some values that should be available as an JVM arguments and some are in properties files. We want to save all of them to DB except DB connection credentials (which we have encrypted so far). All these values are currently referenced as

> ```
> @Value("${service.url}")
> private String url;
> ```

Is there a good resources to follow? Basically, I am looking for some ideas how other people have achieved similar scenarios?